# How to set proxy in HtmlUnit using socketaddress?

Tags: sockets, proxy, htmlunit

i need to know how to set proxy in HtmlUnit using socketaddress?
i have tried with the following..

```
  System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "myHOST");
  System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "myPORT");
  WebClient wb = new WebClient();
  ProxyConfig pro = new ProxyConfig("172.22.218.218", 8085);
  pro.setSocksProxy(true);
  wb.setProxyConfig(pro);
  wb.setRedirectEnabled(true);
```

---

this is where i get error..!

```
HtmlPage p = (HtmlPage) wb.getPage("http://google.com/");
```

---

Answer (score 0):

WebClient has a constructor for that:
[WebClient(BrowserVersion, String, int)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html)

It would be good to know what error.

Comment: this is the error i get...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server